# Node program doesn't stop after unregistering a listener from hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, typescript, hyperledger-fabric

I'm using SDK 1.4, and I'm creating a listener I want to receive a message and close my program but when I do the unregister the program doesn't stop and I can't see in the documentation any other way to stop listening.

Here is the documentation I'm using as guide

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-listening-to-events.html

Here's my code

```
const contract = await fabricService.getContract(user, contractName);

const listener = await contract.addContractListener(
    'tests',
    'contract',
    (_error: Error, event: any, _blockNumber?: string, _transactionId?: string, _status?: string) => {
      console.log('message received');
      const data = (event.payload as Buffer).toString('utf8');
      expect(data).to.equal('xxxx');
      listener.unregister();
    }
);

listener.unregister();
```

I expected the program to end after de listener unregister but nothing happens and the program keeps running.

am I missing something? shouldn't the program stop?

Thanks

Comment: try calling `disconnect` on your created gateway instance

Comment: That was it thanks!!!